# How to check if soft link exists or not

Tags: c, linux, symlink

```
user: ls -lt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user sw-team    9 Jun 18 19:01 new_link -> test/file
```

I have a soft link like mentioned above. I want to check whether new_link(not the linked file) exists or not. I tried all the below but all are checking only if the final destination file (test/file) exists or not.

```
access(filename,F_OK)
stat()
open()
fopen()
```

I want to find it in C language not in shell script.Please tell me how to find if new_link exists before checking the linked file?

Comment: If the symbolic link does not exist, all the mechanisms you tried would report an error. However, they would also report an error if the symbolic link existed but some part of the path it points at causes trouble (does not exist or you don't have permission or isn't a directory when it needs to be one).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`lstat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lstat.html) - get symbolic link status:

> The `lstat()` function shall be equivalent to [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html), except when path refers to a symbolic link. In that case `lstat()` shall return **information about the link**, while [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) shall return information about the file the link references.

(Emphasis mine.)

`lstat` will return non-zero, and `errno` will be set to `ENOENT` if the link (or any other part of the path) does not exist.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

bool symlink_exists(const char* path)
{
    struct stat buf;
    int result;

    result = lstat(path, &buf);

    return (result == 0);
}

void test(const char* path)
{
    bool exists = symlink_exists(path);

    printf("%s does%s exist.\n", path, exists ? "" : " not");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    test("/bin/sh");
    test("/etc/no_such_thing");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
/bin/sh does exist.
/etc/no_such_thing does not exist.
```

Comment: Thanks. but it is not working if i remove the destination file

Comment: @Jonathon the function `symlink_exists` in it's current implementation only answers whether path exists, and not whether path is a symbolic link or regular file. When using `lstat`, **If** path is a symlink, the buffer will hold data about it and not about the pointed data, as opposed to a mere `stat`. But you still need to check the file type (will appear in `st_mode` field in the `struct stat` buffer supplied). See the example in the `man page`

Answer (score 4):

You need `lstat` to get link status and `readlink` to read the value of symlink. 
I have modified Jonthon's code. Check this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

bool symlink_exists(const char* path)
{
    struct stat buf;
    int ret = 0;
    char *linkname;


    if (lstat(path, &buf) == 0) {
       // TODO: Add error handling
       linkname = malloc(buf.st_size + 1);
       readlink(path, linkname, buf.st_size + 1);
       linkname[buf.st_size] = '\0';
       printf("---> '%s' points to '%s'\n", path, linkname);
       if (stat(linkname, &buf) == 0)
           ret = 1;
    }
    return ret;
}

void test(const char* path)
{
    bool exists = symlink_exists(path);

    printf("%s does%s exist.\n", path, exists ? "" : " *not*");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   test("/bin/sh");            //Normal link using relative path - NOT WORKING
   test("/etc/no_such_thing"); //Broken file
   test("tmpp");               //Normal link using absolute path - WORKING 
   test("tmppp");              //Broken link  
   return 0; 
}
```

Use absolute path to create your links. Otherwise you have to convert it to relative paths.

Comment: For reference on how to use `readlink()`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6026838/694576

Comment: memory leak: you never `free()` linkname

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```cpp
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string>

bool symlinkExists(const string &path)
{
    struct stat info;
    return lstat(path.c_str(), &info) == 0;
}
```